I am using PostgreSQL. I am facing an error while inserting values in columns, everything is correct all column names, case sensitive, values
I am learning SQL, here while entering values into the customer table with five columns CustID, CustName, Age, City, Salary. I am entering everything correctly, and case sensitive, but I still get an error.
My command :
INSERT INTO customer (CustID, CustName, Age, City, Salary)
VALUES (1, 'Ajay', 55, 'Delhi', 52000)


ERROR: column "custid" of relation "customer" does not exist
LINE 2:  (CustID, CustName, Age, City, Salary)


show your create table, postgres is always right when they tell you that it doesn't exist

also try to reconstruct your problem here https://dbfiddle.uk/S9ZOHCkV

Please update your question with the ddl statement for the customer table

Never ever use UPPER case in your object names, like table and column names. Never. If you do, you MUST use double quotes " around these names, like "CustID" over and over again. And every time you forget this, will result in an error. Just don't use upper case.

Further to @FrankHeikens advice this SO thread will most probably help you clarify and solve your problem.

Another sidenote: Never store the age in your DB, it changes every year. Simply store the  date of birth. If you need to get the age, calculate it in your query.

Thank you to all for helping me out here, query is resolved

The clue is in the error message. It says

'column "custid" ... does not exist'

Of course, you were trying to insert data into the column CustID, not custid. This may seem confusing, but remember that SQL is not supposed to be a case-sensitive language! We usually use upper and lower case to distinguish keywords from values visually.
The default behaviour is therefore to map all column names in queries to lowercase, so that CustID, CUSTID, and custid are all treated the same.
You can insist on making Postgres case-sensitive using double quotes:
INSERT INTO customer
("CustID", "CustName", "Age", "City", "Salary")
VALUES
(1, 'Ajay', 55, 'Delhi', 52000)

This is, of course, extremely tedious. That is why we usually recommend using snake_case column names (e.g. cust_id), not CamelCase.
